# RealmResults is inaccessible due to its protection level (XAMARIN)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, realm

Here is the part of my code where problem exist. How to solve this issue regarding realmresults saying inaccessible? This is the code I am using from my previous project using 0.80 version of realm. I am now using 2.1.0 realm version. Is there a change the way how to delete an object on realm database after update?

```
public class mydatabase
{
    private Realm realm;

    public void m05_deleteSpecific(int id)
    {
        realm = Realm.GetInstance(DAL_DBAccessVariable.config);

        realm.Write(() =>
        {
            var dbObject = realm.All<DAL_RequestEntity>().Where(c => c.Req_ID == id);
            realm.RemoveRange(((RealmResults<DAL_RequestEntity>)dbObject)); //problem occur here

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **(RealmResults<'DAL_RequestEntity'>)** part of code here is removable

```
//this is what I use since realm version 0.80.0
realm.RemoveRange(((RealmResults<DAL_RequestEntity>)dbObject));
```

my query now is just a simple

```
//this is now my code for realm version 2.1.0
public void m05_deleteSpecific(int id)
{
    realm = Realm.GetInstance(DAL_DBAccessVariable.config);

    realm.Write(() =>
    {
        var dbObject = realm.All<DAL_RequestEntity>().Where(c => c.Req_ID == id);
        realm.RemoveRange(dbObject);
    });
}
```